# Getting street info from Google Maps API

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, dijkstra

On my Android app, I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm for some cities, but I want to give weights to the streets manually. Is there any way I can get a graph of all crossroads of a given city and the streets connecting them using Google Maps Android API for implementing this? If no, is there any other service that will provide me with a similar feature?